# Query XML with dynamic number of elements or attributes?

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have employee table in sql database which has some fixed attributes like employee_id, employee_name and employee_age, I allow user to add n attributes of his choice in UI. I want to write a stored procedure to store the data which user provides for fixed attributes as well as the attributes which he has created.

The solution which i thought was to pass the xml as parameter to stored procedure which will have the following structure. If employee_age is not provided, then its default value is stored.

```
<employee>
  <employee_id>1<employee_id>
  <employee_name>XYZ<employee_name>
  <dynamic_attrib1>2.34</dynamic_attrib1>
  <dynamic_attrib2>abcd</dynamic_attrib2>
<employee>
```

the problem which i am facing is how to parse this xml when i dont know the names of attributes which user is setting in advance? Can i do it this way? Is there any other way in which i can do it? Thanks in advance.. :)

Comment: Hi, is this question still open? Do you need further help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Your given XML is not valid...

What you are trying to do is a pattern called *Key-Value-Pair* (or *Attribute-Value-Pair* or also *Entity-Attribute-Value*) and is always very cumbersome... On the database side it us much better to know the structure of your resultset, otherwise you need (ugly) tricks.

You can transfer your given XML into classical *Key-Value-Pairs* like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<employee>
  <employee_id>1</employee_id>
  <employee_name>XYZ</employee_name>
  <dynamic_attrib1>2.34</dynamic_attrib1>
  <dynamic_attrib2>abcd</dynamic_attrib2>
</employee>';

SELECT Nd.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,Nd.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('employee/*') AS A(Nd);
```

Togehter with a helper table you can change the NodeNames, if there is a corresponding entry:

```
DECLARE @dynAttribs TABLE (AttribName VARCHAR(100),name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dynAttribs VALUES
 ('dynamic_attrib1','Whatever can be 2.34')
,('dynamic_attrib2','Whatever can be "abcd"');

SELECT ISNULL(da.name, Nd.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)')) AS NodeName
      ,Nd.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('employee/*') AS A(Nd)
LEFT JOIN @dynAttribs AS da ON Nd.value('local-name(.)','varchar(max)')=da.AttribName;
```

You might even include a datatype to your helper table, but this would force you do use dynamically created statements and `EXEC`.

Better than your XML would be something like this:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
'<employee>
  <employee_id>1</employee_id>
  <employee_name>XYZ</employee_name>
  <DynamicAttributes>
      <attribute name="testname1">2.34</attribute>
      <attribute name="testname2">abcd</attribute>
  </DynamicAttributes>
</employee>';

SELECT e.value('employee_id[1]','int') AS Employee_Id
      ,e.value('employee_name[1]','varchar(max)') AS Employee_Name
      ,da.value('@name','varchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,da.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('employee') AS A(e)
OUTER APPLY e.nodes('DynamicAttributes/*') AS B(da);
```

But your question does not provide enough details: What are you going to do with this? Is the structure (maybe later!) more complex (inner nested elements like address, phone number(s))? It was much better to define a sure set of attributes and allow the customer to define which of them are not used. Maybe allow them to give individual names (aliases). But I would not advise you to offer a completely open *do-it-yourself* database. You will get into deep troubles...